# "Conditional" join to different tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 databases where I need to extract data (let's call them DB1, DB2 and DB3).

From DB1, I select a query that returns something like this:

```
ORDER      DESC      TOTAL    ORGANIZATION
=============================================
262     Order1    5129       116
629     Order2    123        138
915     Order3    95         138
159     Order4    1932       116
```

From DB2 and DB3 I select this info (both tables are the same, but with different data from separate organizations)

DB2 (ORG 116):

```
ORDER     TYPE
==================
262      2
159      5
856      3
629      2
```

DB3 (ORG 138):

```
ORDER     TYPE
==================
629      1
915      4
012      1
262      5
```

As you can see, both organizations can have them same order number but different types.

How can I join DB1 with DB2 and/or DB3 to extract the TYPE column, but looking for a different DB depending on DB1 organization's column?

The result would be like this:

```
ORDER      DESC      TOTAL    ORGANIZATION     TYPE
===========================================================
262     Order1    5129          116             2
629     Order2    123           138             1
915     Order3    95            138             4
159     Order4    1932          116             5
```

For ORDER 262 I got Type 2 from DB2 (not from DB3 because ORG is 116) and for ORDER 629 I got Type 1 from DB3 (not from DB2 because ORG is 138).

My simplified query would be like this (I am using WITH...AS because queries are very long and each one comes from a different server, so this way everything seems more organized) :

```
With EAM as (
Select Order, Desc, Total, Organization
from Table1
),
AP116 as (
select order, type
from table2
),
AP138 as (
select order, type
from table3
)
select *
from EAM inner join AP116 on EAM.order = AP116.order
```

This query works fine but links all orders with AP116. I need to use a CASE or something to let me select AP116 or AP138 depending on the ORG on that last line.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to all tables and just select the value you need with a `CASE` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a discrete set of different databases, I would suggest writing this as a union:

```
Select Order, Desc, Total, Organization, Table2.Type
from Table1
join Table2 on...
where Organization = 116

union

Select Order, Desc, Total, Organization, Table3.Type
from Table1
join Table3 on...
where Organization = 138
```